# React-native item is cropped by container

Tags: javascript, css, android-layout, layout, react-native

I have problem with android layout and don't know how to solve it. The code is here https://rnplay.org/apps/XD0WGw on iOS all working fine, but on Android the half of circle "avatar" is hidden by "infContainer", [this is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJkt1.png). I tried to use z-index but it's not working.Circle part should be visible on infContainer. Please help :)

Comment: Please post some code and details, this question ist very unspecific.

Comment: there is link where is code.